# Is Millenial a common term?

Tags: word-usage

I would like to use the word "Millenial" in an article. This is a reference to people between (roughly) 18-30. Is this a common enough term to use? Will the average reader know exactly what I am talking about?

Comment: No. It should be spelled _Millennial_ and it's been in use for a long time and it only occasionally means what you describe as its "reference". Thus, the average reader is unlikely to understand what you are talking about without a lot of help from you. This is generally true for all readers and writers.

Comment: I have heard it more and more recently....there's a mention of the term, spelled, as John Lawler says, *millennials,* [in Wikipedia's Generation Y article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_Y) Maybe Generation Y would be more widely understood.

Comment: I've *never* heard this meaning, and to be honest if someone used it I would think them ignorant, not erudite. Particularly so soon after we've just started a new **millennium**, making the *relating to a thousand years* meaning positively commonplace.

Comment: @JLG: That's a pretty daft usage meaning *"the generation born shortly before or after the new millennium"*, not *"people aged 18-30"*.

Comment: I used this word but I don't know about "18-30 yrs". My understanding is that a person who lives in 2 millenniums(end of one and beginning of other) is a millennial.

Answer (score 2):

The term *Millennial* has been used by news sources such as [CNN](http://money.cnn.com/2011/05/18/news/economy/millennial_generation_workers/index.htm), [Time Magazine](http://moneyland.time.com/2012/04/27/millennials-are-biggest-suckers-for-selfish-impulse-buys/), and [USA Today](http://www.usatoday.com/money/perfi/basics/story/2012-04-23/millenials-financial-knowledge/54494856/1) to describe people approximately between the ages of 18 and 30. However, note that each source also explicitly defines the relevant age group within the article, and note also that they are all less than 14 months old and were written for a US news-consuming audience. So, the term may still not be immediately clear to most readers. I'll add that the term *Generation Y* is much more familiar to me than *Millennial*, and conclude by saying that whatever word you choose should be tailored to your audience.